# add more methods to class using include_once

Tags: php, methods

I have an script that was written by a different developer. I need to expand the class's capabilities. I want to write my own methods on a different .php file. and use something like include_once

I've tried adding this on the constructor like:

```
class confusing_developer {
    public function __construct(){
        $this->$id 'blah blah blah';
        include_once "myMods.php";
```

and my myMods.php continues like:

```
private function banana(){
....
```

However, this does not work.  Do you guys know any other alternative??

Comment: you don't want to expand, but extend the class...

Comment: Exactly:  "don't try to change the other programmer's source code – "super-class it!"